# Checking existence of a sqlite db in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

When my app runs it first checks for the existence of the db. The first time it runs the db should not exist and if that's the case it will create the dB's tables, then it will populate specific tables with various support data. So, in testing this works fine. So I then delete the db through adb shell. Then I rerun the app and it determines that the db still  exists!! I have 2 different methods that checks existence, or not,and both behave in the same aberrant way.
Method 1 simply tries to open the db as a Java file and then uses the exists method to check. Method 2 is a bit more elaborate using the db path and name as args to thedb.open database method.
Both methods fail to determine that the db does not exist, after I delete it in adb shell.
I can provide the code if needed, but thought I'd see if there are some ideas for this behavior. I have cycled the genymotion emulator but this did not fix it.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: So you are deleting the db file through adb shell while you are running the app?

Comment: Why aren't you using `SQLiteOpenHelper`?

Answer (score 0):

No. I stop the app, delete the db, then restart (All in Android Studio). By the way. Do you know why the db path, as reported by Gene motion, is not the same as my apps db path? Both tho do point to the same db, as shown in adb.